# Problema com toFixed em retorno Json

Tags: javascript, json

Estou com problemas para usar `toFixed` em um retorno `json`.

Uma parte do código

```
success: function (dados){
                $.each(dados, function(index){
                    var guidPedido              = dados[index].guid;
                    var statusPedido            = dados[index].status;
                    var nomePedido              = dados[index].nome;
                    var enderecoPedido      = dados[index].endereco;
                    var totalPedido             = dados[index].total;
                    var dataPedido              = dados[index].data;
                    var telefonePedido      = dados[index].telefone;
                    var numerocasaPedido    = dados[index].numero;
                    var formaPagamento      = dados[index].formaPagamento;
                    var observacaoPedido    = dados[index].observacao;
                    var cpfClientePedido    = dados[index].cpf;
                    var entregarPedido      = dados[index].entregar;
                    var tokenPedido             = dados[index].token;
                    var bairroPedido            = dados[index].bairro;
                    var pagamentotext       = 0;

                    if (statusPedido == 1) {
                        var statuspedidotext = "Processando";
                    }

                    if (formaPagamento == 0) {
                        pagamentotext = "Dinheiro";
                    } else {
                        pagamentotext = "Cartão/Crédito/Débito";
                    }

                    totalPedido = totalPedido.toFixed(2);
```

O erro é:

> ERRO: lanc_pedidos.php:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'toFixed' of null

Após retirar a possibilidade de `dados[index].total` ser `null`, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: totalPedido.toFixed is not a function

Alguém pode me explicar o que há de errado ?

Comment: Esse erro quer dizer que `dados[index].total` é `null`. Esse valor pode ser `null`? caso "sim" queres converter `null` para zero? caso "não" tens um erro noutro lado que tens de corrigir primeiro

Comment: certo agora apresenta isto TypeError: totalPedido.toFixed is not a function

Comment: Ok, o que dá `console.log(typeof dados[index].total, dados[index].total);`?

Comment: Consegui sérgio, da seguinte forma 
totalPedido = parseFloat(totalPedido).toFixed(2);

Comment: Ok, estavas a receber uma string então. Otimo. Se já resolveste podes apagar a pergunta talvez... ou responder.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda sérgio, vou responder e deixar caso alguem tenha o mesmo problema

Comment: Se vais responder indica com detalhe o _Type_ da variável, e porque é que o erro apareceu e o que faz o `parseFloat`:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) é um método para converter números em strings. Ou seja um método para variáveis de tipo *Number*. O erro que te dá diz-me que estás a receber uma *String*.

Repara o exemplo:

```
var totalPedido = '10';
totalPedido.toFixed(2);
```

isto dá o erro que viste:

> VM329:1 Uncaught TypeError: totalPedido.toFixed is not a function(…)

Se a tua variável tivesse um *Numero* isso já não acontecia:

```
var totalPedido = 10;
totalPedido.toFixed(2); // dá "10.00"
```

Assim, primeiro tens de converter o teu texto com numeros dentro (*type String*) para um número e depois limitar as casa decimais convertendo de volta em *String*.

Para converter em número podes usar o `Number()` ou o `parseFloat`. Assim o teu código poderia ser:

```
var totalPedido = Number(dados[index].total).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Perfeito, era este mesmo o problema, muito bem explicado

Answer (score 2):

O Problema vinha que o valor retornado era uma string

```
TypeError: totalPedido.toFixed is not a function
```

solução converter para float

```
totalPedido = parseFloat(totalPedido).toFixed(2);
```